# Add rank for each row group as a new column in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ranking, ssrs-tablix

In SSRS I am trying to add a rank as a new column and ranking should be based of **"New Deals(#)"** field. Also ranking should start from 1 for every **Region**. Please see the screen shot for reference. I don't want the ranking to be done on stored Procedure, so could someone suggest me a way to have a rank on SSRS based off of a filed inside a row group.

[image: Desired Output format]

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h2A5.png)

Comment: The best way to do this is in the stored procedure.   Why would you prefer an inferior solution?

Comment: The stored procedure is not aggregated and has of lot of other details. So I cannot modify the stored proc to add ranking based on grouping.

Comment: You can't EASILY modify the stored procedure, but you can.   You would just have to do the aggregations and calculate the rank somewhere in the logic, and then attach it to the results based on the PBM Name.

Comment: I completely agree with you Tab, even my approach was to modify the SP. But I don't have permissions to do so and I was asked not modify the SP and do all my calculations on SSRS end :(

Answer (score 1):

Use an expression in the field

```
=RowNumber("Your Region Group Name Here")
```

That will generate a new row number sequence for each region.  The number assigned will be based on the sort order of the group.

Of course you would not be able to use this row number to order your data.

Incidentally, the best way to do this would be in the stored procedure.  That way it becomes part of your data, allowing you to sort the region by another field (name perhaps) without changing the rankings assigned.

Comment: It didn't work, this is not generating new row number sequence by region.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your design view?  You may need to move the expression to the dataset as a calculated field.  As before, this is best done in the stored procedure as you won't have to jump through as many steps to use it.

Comment: I don't see any option to add a screen shot in the comments.

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: Got it. Added the screenshot to the question. Thank you.

Comment: The new screenshot shows a column group, what does that represent in the original screenshot?

Comment: Sorry ignore that I was trying something. There is no column group.

Comment: Can you paste the expression you used for RowNumber in the field?

Comment: =RowNumber("Region2")

Comment: Try using the detail group ("HP_PCM...").  Its been a while since I used RowNumber in the report, I always do it in the stored procedure because it is so much cleaner.

Comment: no luck :( It's still giving some random ranks. Even I wanted to add it to SP but client didn't gave us permissions to modify the SP. That's why I am trying my luck with SSRS.

Comment: I had a chance to test it.  My original answer does work.  If you create a field in the detail row, with the RowNumber expression scoped to the parent group, the row number will reset for each group.  There must be some other factor that hasn't been mentioned that would prevent it from working.  Good luck.